# value.Format is not function error in angular 13

Tags: angular, momentjs

Hi All I'm trying create custom pipe for date formatting using moment. I have written below code for Pipe.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import {Moment} from 'moment';

@Pipe({
 name: 'MyDateFormatPipe',
})
export class DateFormatPipe implements PipeTransform {
transform(value: Moment, ...args: any[]) {
const format = args && args.length === 1 ? args[0] : null;

switch (format) {
  case 'withTime':
    return value ? value.format('DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss') : '';
  case 'withTimePmAm':
    return value ? value.format('MMM, DD, YYYY h:mm:ss A') : '';
  default:
    return value ? value.format(format ?? 'DD-MM-YYYY') : '';
}
}
}
```

And I'm calling above pipe from my ts file. code written that for below.

```
     valueGetter = (datePipe: DateFormatPipe, format: any) => 
  (params: any) => {
   console.log('in valueGetter', params);
   const valKey = params.colDef.field;
   const keys = valKey.split('.');
   let value = params.data;
   if (keys.length > 1) {
    for (const key of keys) {
    if (typeof value === 'object' && value !== null && value[key] 
  !== undefined) {
      value = value[key];
    }
    }
    } else {
   value = params.data[valKey]; 
   // output of value is -> '2023-12-01T00:00:00'
     }
   return isMoment(value) ? datePipe.transform(value, format) : 
   value;
   };
```

But I'm getting below error.

**isMoment(value) always return false and not moving in pipe file**  (Please help me to solve this error...)

Comment: Can you setup a stackblitz enviroment? The `for` loop is a bit weird (value is incrementing itself, and there is no break). I dont see anything wrong, because, every code without info to what it should be, is correct.

Comment: Actually I'm getting to many values from response. for iterating that response values I used for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code you provided, it looks like you are using the isMoment function to check if a value is an instance of Moment class from the moment library. However, the error you mentioned indicates that isMoment(value) is always returning false.

The issue might be related to how you are importing the Moment class from the moment library in your pipe file. Make sure you are importing it correctly using the appropriate import statement. Here's an example of how you can import the Moment class from the moment library:

```
import { Moment } from 'moment/moment';
```

Note that the import statement may vary depending on the version and configuration of the moment library you are using in your Angular project. Make sure to check the documentation and import the Moment class accordingly.

Also, make sure that you have installed the moment library as a dependency in your Angular project. You can install it using npm or yarn, for example:

```
npm install moment
```

If you are still encountering the issue after checking the import statement and installing the moment library, please provide more information about your Angular project setup, including the versions of Angular and moment library you are using, and any other relevant code or error messages.

Comment: I have imported isMoment like   `import { isMoment } from 'moment';`  As you said to import Moment then how we can get isMoment there.